# JLabel instance is not showing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java Swing and I have a code that I want to modify. I just want to add another button; the way it is shown below in `code 1`, but at run time it does not show. `code1` it is the code I want to add to `code 2`.

**code 1**

```
    JLabel process = new JLabel ("process:");
    final JTextField Tprocess = new JTextField ("Process", 40);
    final JButton btn_ProcessFile = new JButton ("ProcessFile");
```

**Code 2**

```
    JLabel Ldatei = new JLabel ("Datei auswählen:");
    final JTextField Tdatei = new JTextField ("", 20);
    final JButton Bsearch = new JButton ("Datei wählen");
```

Comment: Show the code where you use the defined objects.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `validate()` on the frame after adding it

Comment: Assuming that the OP has actually added the label to something, which was already displayed on the screen `revalidate` and `repaint` would be better choices...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks I will try them out soon, i always have problems with the components not refreshing when using repaint. But revalidate sounds logical :)